# How to run a sub-script inside another script launched by another script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I have a script which is calling another script  by:

```
   IPython.get_ipython().magic('run doit.py')
```

In doit.py, this is calling another script called doit_2.py.

Usually, doit_2.py does not execute, we need to copy and paste doit_2.py into doit.py to make it executed.

```
doit_2.py uses variables defined in do_it.py
do_it.py also uses variables defined in doit_2.py
(obviously in logical order, doit_2.py can be thought as C++ include ).
```

Wondering, if there is a way to execute a sub-script inside a script executed by another script ?

Comment: do you get any error message ? show in question. Maybe it runs in different folder so it need full path.

Comment: If it's getting complex enough that you're talking about 'sub-scripts', it's probably a good idea to write your code in functions, and then import and call them. There are a lot of tools and experience for using importable modules to build bigger systems, and doing it with scripts and the run magic throws that away.

Comment: Cannot use functions, since the script is provided by 3rd provider/people, so need to include to run into a batch.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information about `doit` and `doit_2` to help.

Comment: added some precisions.